# Mostrar el texto seleccionado dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Tengo un `dropdown` que lleno con `AJAX` de forma dinamica y se muestra correctamente, necesito mostrar el seleccionado, he intentado con esto sin resultados:

```
 alert($('#ul_sucursal').find('option:selected').text());
 alert($( "#ul_sucursal option:selected" ).text());



<ul id="ul_sucursal" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <!-- lo lleno con ajax-->                   
</ul>

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= base_url() ?>DashboardOTController/ListarSucursales",
            success: function(obj){



               $.each(obj.Sucursales.sucursales, function (ind, elem) {//inserta en el ul li de sucursal

                $('#ul_sucursal').append('<li><a href="#"  value="'+elem.id_sucursal+'">'+elem.nombre_sucursal+'</a></li>');


              });
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres mostrar el `value` de lo que selecciono, usa el `onclick` del anchor tag:

```
$('#ul_sucursal').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="alert('+elem.id_sucursal+')" value="'+elem.id_sucursal+'">'+elem.nombre_sucursal+'</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Como los datos se agregan dinamicamente con `AJAX` el evento se debe capturar de la siguiente manera:

```
$("ul_sucursal").on("click", "a",function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
//para que no nos lleve el link a algun lugar
var valor = $(this).attr("value");

alert("este es mi valor" + valor)
});
```